# Get the value from dropdown array using codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm new in codeigniter framework, I just want to get the values from selected dropdown array in my form using CI. Assumed these are the whole process.

I have form with auto populated cities,

example in view

```
<select name="city[]">
<option value="ABC"> ABC </option>
</select>

<select name="city[]">
<option value="EFG"> EFG </option>
</select>
```

Here is the controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city[]', 'city');
```

When I echo it out on my model form

```
echo $this->input->post('city');
```

it just shows array, Any ideas?

Comment: Because it is an array and contains multiple values. And because you can't `echo` an array. Use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to see what's inside and access a specific value if you'd like or loop through the array if you want all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because is an array :D.

When you `echo` a variable of type array it shows `"Array"`, do a `print_r` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your view should look like -

```
<select name="city[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="ABC"> ABC </option>
  <option value="EFG"> EFG </option>
</select>
```

**PHP:**

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->input->post('city'));
```